# Call stack variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, closures

I read somewhere that whenever a function gets called, the compiler puts all the visible variables on a stack, somewhat related to closures as well, now with the following code I'm not really sure if it'd work in a concurrent environment like node.js.

```
Product.prototype.list = function(body) {
    body.options = {
        hostname: endPoints.product,
        path: '/applications/' + body.entityType
        method: 'GET'
    };
    return remote.request(body)
        .then(function(result){
            body[body.entityType] = result;
            return body;
        });
};
```

Now if the following two function gets called concurrently using promises, will a closure occur? For instance

```
product.list({entityType: "coke"})
    .then(console.log); //will this have {coke: []} or {pepsi: []}

product.list({entityType: "pepsi"})
    .then(console.log);
```

Comment: I guess that depends on what `product` is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a closure will be created by the anonymous function you pass to `then`. The variable which is being closed over is the `body` value being passed in to the outer `list` function.

Each time you call `list` - in the above example you've called it twice - you are adding some values to the `body` object and then instantiating a new closure and making that value available for it. The values that you're passing to each call of `list` are both object literals which means they're completely separate and you will be handing different values to the closure so there is no way the call involving 'coke' will ever have a connection to the call involving 'pepsi'.

Comment: for more information about time of closure creation, is that closure created when the function `list` is called or when `.then` is called?

Comment: @user2727195 - The closure is created when the `list()` function is called, as the free variable `body` is passed in, defined, and remember in that scope, which is also available in the `remote.request().then(...` function because it's lexical.